# Capturing one excel sheet

Tags: linux, excel, shell, apache-poi, mutt

I am sending an email from a server(using mutt command), with excel file attached to it. This file has 40 sheets. This is all done in a shell script.

The first sheet being a "Analysis" sheet with few rows and columns.

I want to send screenshot/data of only the first sheet in the email's body. Is there a way to do it inside a shellscript?

Any help is appreciated

Comment: you can probably do this with Powershell scripting, but it doesn't sound like you're running your `mutt` on a Windows machine. The most pragmatic solution is to add a step on the Windows-side that creates/extracts just what you need as a separate file, maybe with `.AnalysisSummary.xls` appended on the filename. There may be `perl` (or `python`) code that you can call to perform such a task, but that is a whole separate problem to get resolved. Good luck.

Comment: AND, sorry to say, but requests for this sort of issue are off-topic on StackOverflow. (Maybe https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com ). Please read  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask ,  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  and take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

You have several options:

- If you want to send an actual screenshot, then you can use the PrintSc command by clicking Alt+PrintSc on your keyboard then pasting in the image directly into the email (depending on your email client) or pasting it in a image program like paint then saving it as an image then attaching it (this works if you have Windows, comment if you have Mac)
- If you want to send the actual date just on the first sheet, but the data has formulas connected to other sheets, then copy the data in the first sheet and paste the values/format into a new document, and you can send that.
- Alternatively, you can Print as a PDF the first sheet.